# Set Custom Indentation and Hanging in Powerpoint Table using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to put bullet for a paragraph inside a table in powerpoint and then set indentation before text: 0.13 and Special/Hanging by 0.13 for that bullet point. I am able to achieve this but the problem is that if there are multiple paragraphs inside that table cell all the paragraphs get intended by the given values.

`ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels(1).LeftMargin = 72 * 0.13 * 1`

I am using this which works on the complete cell rather than on just that particular paragraph.

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Paragraphs.IndentLevel = 3
```

I also tried using IndentLevel, it works on that particular paragraph only but I don't get the values of 0.13 for indentation before text and Hanging. Is there even a way to do this?
I've been stuck at this for the complete day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the paragraphs as follows:

```
Option Explicit

' ********************************************************************************
' PowerPoint VBA Macro written by Jamie Garroch of http://YOUpresent.co.uk/
' Purpose : Set the Hanging ruler spacing for the selected text range
' Inputs  : None
' Outputs : None
' ********************************************************************************
Sub SetBulletHanging()
  Dim x As Long
  With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2
    For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
      With .Paragraphs(x).ParagraphFormat
        .FirstLineIndent = -72 * 0.13 * 1
      End With
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works to some extent for me. I am now able to iterate the paragraphs but .FirstLineIndent sets the value of Special:First Line as 0.13 whereas I need to set Special:Hanging. Also can you tell me what should I use in place of .FirstLineIndent to modify the value of Indentation before text.

Comment: ok got it I have to use a negative number for Hanging. Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed

Comment: Cool. I updated it to be negative. Could you up vote the answer if you're happy with it?